# search GPS enabled devices around my gps device using phonegap

Tags: cordova, gps, bluetooth

Can I search GPS enabled devices around my GPS device using phonegap as bluetooth's scan devices functionality. If this is possible, how can I achieve it.?
To be more specific, my requirement is like this... Suppose, I am at location "xyz", now I want to get list of devices around me that has GPS enabled.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible out of the box. You need some kind of publish/subscribe service or mechanism for location exchange (for further processing of other locations, e.g. distances to other devices). Look for [google latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Latitude) for example or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html).

NOTE : Try to develop application using above link.

and must and should test in android mobile, because emulator not show the gps Loccation values.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The solution gets the own position but he asked for a solution that searches other device positions, too. This is not possible without an extra service, discovery is not part of the (GPS) API of PhoneGap.